# Review audits need to be picked better

Tags: support, review-audits, specific-audit

I just failed [an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/30475337), because I voted to close a very short-looking question.

This question is [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), but I filtered it with [discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.js). As usual, it showed the [discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.js) tag along with the other tags, but I think audits should be picked more carefully. Discord.js is a **[Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)** package. It usually gets [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js) tags on its questions (and [has never](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.js%20c%2B%2B) gotten a [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag on a question), so I would assume the audit would be JavaScript or Node.js if the system can't find an audit for discord.js, yet I still got this C++ question... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> …because I voted to close a very short-looking question.

Well, sounds like to me the audits are working exactly as designed, at least in this case. (There *are* some bad audits, of course, and I'd love to see that fixed, ideally by a system where moderators can nominate and curate the posts that are selected as audits, both true-positives and false-positives. But this isn't a bad audit.)

Hopefully, you learned that the length of the question is nothing more than a *potential indicator* of its quality—something that should make you think twice—not a sufficient reason to close the question.

Hopefully, you also learned that, if you do not feel you have the subject-matter expertise to judge the quality of a question, then you should "Skip" the review task.

You seem to have been able to judge that the question was not a Discord.js question, so why would you judge it with the standards of Discord.js questions? With a question that is as short as that one, it is surely not too much to ask that you hover over the link and/or read the comments to figure out the real context. That would have been paying enough attention to pass the audit. As would have editing to fix the apparently-incorrect tags.

Comment: I understand that the length of the question does not determine the quality now, but I would still like to see the audits have related tags only in the filter

Comment: That's not really how audits work. Audits lie to you, with the explicit intention of checking to see if you are paying close enough attention to see through the lies.

Comment: It would make it very hard to choose the right option if it's a completely unrelated tag though... I guess "Skip" is the best option I could have clicked

Comment: Surely a question having a wrong tag is a reason to edit, not to close, unless "Incorrectly tagged" is now a close reason. I fail to see any possible argument where closing for the tag is valid.

Comment: @MrMythical - The alternative to skipping a review task, open the question in another tab, to verify that the question still exists and/or is actually closed. Audits are designed to be passed, getting in a habit of opening questions that appear to be audits in another tab, isn't cheating to pass the audit.  You are practicing good reviewer habits. In this case there was absolutely nothing wrong with that question, voting to close a perfectly valid question, only creates more work for everyone else.